# How to retrieve the Node of a treepanel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree, extjs4, treepanel

I am using ExtJS 4.
I have created a tree panel as

```
var treeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        root: {
            text:'Reports',
            expanded: true,
            children: [
                {
                    id: 'operationalNode',
                    text: 'Operational',
                    children: [{ text: "report1", leaf: true }]
                },
                {
                    id: 'managementNode',
                    text: 'Management',
                    children: [{ text: "report2", leaf: true }]
                },
                {
                    id: 'inventoryNode',
                    text: 'Inventory'
                }
            ]
        }
    });
var treePanel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.TreePanel',{
    animate:true,
    layout:'fit',
    height:400,
    store:treeStore
    });
```

Now I want to retrieve the 'Operational' child as

```
Ext.getCmp('operationalNode');
```

But it returns null.

**Why is it so?**

**How can I retrieve that Node?**

**Is there any way to retrieve the Node by its name?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nodes are actual models that have the node interface . so you should just use getNodeById from the treestore

```
var node = treeStore.getNodeById('operationalNode')
```

your data is in node.data just like in any other models

Answer (score 0):

You gonna need something like this:

```
Ext.getCmp('id-of-the-view').getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
```

Comment: sorry for the comment but he didn't ask to retrieve a selected node

Comment: The people that answer on ExtJS questions are small at number so I decided to share idea even if it's not the best one.

Comment: As I said I just give some option, I'm not so good in ExtJS, my answer was in case that noone else answer as it happens not once for me. But now he can use yours!

Comment: it was not an offence sry, i just pointed out the problem so he doesn't start on the wrong path, in extjs using ext.getCmp is very costly because it searches in the whole dom which is pretty big for a normal extjs project.